# hibernate list of parameters

Tags: hibernate

I need to write a general function that handle queries. 
the function get `List<String>` that hold parameters that is sent to the `query`. 
how i implement that in `hibernate`.

to be more particular, if my query is:

```
select * from people where name=:name and family=:family
```

my list will contain

```
<"name","myname">
<"family","myfamily">
```

Comment: better way to use queryString

Answer (score 1):

getHibernateTemplate() is most probably returning a org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate which is a Hibernate helper class in the spring framework. This is the code from the find method called therein:

```
    public List find(final String queryString, final Object[] values) throws DataAccessException {
    return (List) executeWithNativeSession(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
            Query queryObject = session.createQuery(queryString);
            prepareQuery(queryObject);
            if (values != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    queryObject.setParameter(i, values[i]);
                }
            }
            return queryObject.list();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter list to inlcude in your query with 'IN' and 'setParameterList'

```
List<String> yourListString = new ArrayList<String>();

Query query = getSession().createQuery("select * from people where name in (:yourListString) and family in (:yourListString)"
query.setParameterList("yourListString ", yourListString);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Hibernate Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

This should get you started.

Comment: thanks, the problem is that i can't build the sql with creteria, because all the sql is passed as param to the function.

Answer (score 0):

write query as:

```
String str="select * from people where name=? and family=?";
List<Object> queryParam=new ArrayList<Object>();
queryParam.add(name); //queryParam.add(yourList.get(0));
queryParam.add(family); //queryParam.add(yourList.get(1));
List<Object[]> List=getHibernateTemplate().find(str,queryParam.toArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i understand that i should creat a list that has a param name followed by it's value. 
i didn't understand what is the line with getHibernateTemplate

Comment: It will return HibernateTemplate we can say that this is a helper class which will execute your query and return objects.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you want a generalized way to call a query that used named parameters, passing in a list that contains the the name/value pairs to bind.

This is pretty simple. I'm omitting the use of generics for clarity.

```
    String query="select p from Person p where name=:name and family=:family";
    String[] parameterArray = new String[] {"name", "myName", "family","myFamily"}; 
    List parameters = Arrays.asList(parameterArray);
    List results = callQuery(session, query, parameters);

public List callQuery(Session session, String query, List parameters) {
      Query query = session.createQuery(query);
      if (parameters != null && !parameters.isEmpty()) {
          for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i+=2) {
            query.setParameter(parameters[i],parameters[i+1]);
          }
      }
      return query.list();
    }
```

An alternative is to use a Map, which makes iterating through the parameters to add them to the query a little cleaner; I also find it makes adding them to the collection to pass in to the generic method clearer, as well:

```
    String query="select p from Person p where name=:name and family=:family";
    Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    parameters.put("name","myName");
    parameters.put("family,"myFamily");
    List results = callQuery(session, query, parameters);

public List callQuery(Session session, String query, Map<String,Object> parameters) {
      Query query = session.createQuery(query);
      if (parameters != null && !parameters.isEmpty()) {
          for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : parameters) {
            query.setParameter(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
          }
      }
      return query.list();
    }
```

I'd also recommend looking into NamedQueries over the use of inline strings, as they let you include the queries in your mapping xml/annotations and add some query syntax validation.